# Code not calculating final count as per rate correctly

Tags: python

I was trying to solve the following Problem Statement:

> In the city A, there is a disease x, spreading at the rate of 2. The
>   rate doubles after every 3 days.
>
> If 2 people were initially infected with the disease, how many people
>   will be affected in total after 100 days?
>
> (Hint: Ni+1 = Ni + a*Ni *t where Ni is the ith day patients and Ni+1
>   is patients the day after that, a is the increase rate and t is the
>   number of days.)

This is the Python code I tried to solve the statement:

```
rate = 2
rate_of_rate = 2    # the rate doubles every gap days
gap = 3
initially_infected = 2
final_day = 100

infected = initially_infected
days_passed = 1

while days_passed != final_day:
    if days_passed%gap == 0:
        rate *= rate_of_rate
    infected = infected * rate
    days_passed += 1
print(infected)
```

The answer expected is: `658781418`

And the answer I'm getting is:

```
7387586092700242099654546576830696772603866567292789055868426442323956818125567473217880665869221255368279336978185916233370357196371072076345487974033022845153783727077340269105240653596212209328236829977000561171160601353019714984950312214004440228069460097961675499715690703175560410535127557079386864191774441606293810308368351268196693882638167250873667663250863266951807800784887663781068841491777971210302562177144021123949168116897834247743963522769738506629596576834286879022276623596962844306405686165635072
```

Where am I doing wrong?

P.S. > I am also not able to understand where the formula is incorporating `rate_of_rate`

Comment: I think the problem is the way in which you are interpreting rate.

Comment: Yes, you should look up exponential growth: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_growth#Biology

Comment: I mean the way you are interpreting the doubling of rate ,the answer will be very large as you are getting. I think the rate here should represent absolute number , though in that case too I am getting answer  only in range of correct answer  not exactly the correct answer.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/nXBB66rE   , i am interpreting rate in this way

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 are you sure about the answer?

Comment: I am not sure, but it would be better if you  could  provide question with link or screenshot

Comment: I venture to say that this assignment is poorly worded.  I fail to see how any one can arrive at 658781418.  Might we know the source of this assignment?

Comment: @Rexovas, College professor. I have put a mail to him regarding this. Hope he responds soon :)

Comment: It just doesn't make sense.  If the rate "doubles" every 3 days, that means after 100 days the rate of infection is `17,179,869,184`.  Updating the infected count by either multiplying or adding by the rate up to 100 days will ALWAYS be larger than the expected 658 million.  It just doesn't make sense.  The formula also doesn't make sense, since according to it, after 0 days, infected is 2.  After 1 day, infected is 6 `Ni + 1 = 2 + (2*2)*1` (only this one makes sense), and after 2 days, infected is 30 `Ni+1 = 6 + (6*2)*2)`, at that rate, the number would still be much higher after 100 days.

Comment: @Rexovas, he accepted that the answer he's provided is wrong. But he has no idea what the right answer is in that case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program is perfectly correct.

Even if the disease would be

- spreading at a **constant** rate 2, and
- initially would be infected **only 1 man**, and
- instead of 100 days would be only **63** days,

your task would be an analogy of well-known “[Wheat and chessboard problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheat_and_chessboard_problem)” with the result as large as `18,446,744,073,709,551,615`.

From the Wikipedia “[Wheat and chessboard problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheat_and_chessboard_problem)”:

> If a chessboard were to have wheat placed upon each square such that
>   one grain were placed on the first square, two on the second, four on
>   the third, and so on (doubling the number of grains on each subsequent
>   square), how many grains of wheat would be on the chessboard at the
>   finish?

Comment: Hmm.. so you mean my professor's answer must be a typo?

Comment: "Typo" is a very modest word for it, his problem would kill a whole mankind.